# Paper-Button always as upper case

Tags: polymer

I am using Paper-Button but I am facing issue that the button text always gets capitalized instead or normal case.
I do not see any CSS or Javascript property being applied to make it upper case.

How should I resolve this problem?

Comment: I'm not known with the paper-button, but i think you can overwrite it with css or javascript to make it lowercase?

Comment: It is applied with CSS: https://github.com/Polymer/paper-button/blob/master/paper-button.css

Answer (score 140):

I had the same issue and I solved the problem via adjusting the default theme. Add the following code to a file (name of your choice).js

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme({      
  typography: {
    button: {
      textTransform: 'none'
    }
  }
});

export default theme;
```

You can then add the file to your app in index.js. I named it theme.js:

```
...
import theme from './theme';    
...
const app = () => (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <CssBaseline />
    <App />
  </ThemeProvider>
);

ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: button: {
      textTransform: 'none'
    }

this resolved for me. Thumbs Up

Comment: Worked for me, thanks. I got a warning about `createMuiTheme` being deprecated but had no problem swapping it for `createTheme` as suggested.

Comment: This is nice, but I'm really struggling with the object structure. Say, I want to change the shadow spread now; how do I know which properties inside which objects do I need to change?

Comment: @ankush981 Take a look at: https://mui.com/customization/default-theme/ for possible options and here:  https://bareynol.github.io/mui-theme-creator/

Answer (score 102):

As was mentioned in the comments above, the [material design spec for buttons](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html#) specifies that the text should be uppercase, but you can easily override its CSS property:

```
paper-button {
  text-transform: none;
}
```

Comment: No, this is not specified. The spec even says that contained buttons can be in sentence case: https://material.io/components/buttons/#contained-button

Answer (score 69):

Inspired by the the CSS style above here is the inline styling for localized Button text  transformation -

```
import {Button} from '@material-ui/core';

// Begin Component Logic
 
<Button style={{textTransform: 'none'}}>
   Hello World
</Button>

// End Component Logic
```

Comment: simple and elegant solution.

Answer (score 16):

If you use Mui 5 then you can use the  `sx` syntax

```
<Button sx={{textTransform: "none"}}/>
```

Answer (score 2):

in MUI 5

```
<Button
    sx={{textTransform: 'none'}}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Material UI v5.0+, you can easily approach that with this:

```
import { Button } from "@mui/material";

<Button sx={{textTransform : "none"}}>Your text here</Button>
```