# I can't locate element in cypress because the css selector is changing each time

Tags: automation, cypress

I'm using this code to locate element in order to click into it but that `jss403` change everytime

```
cy.get('.jss403 > .MuiButtonBase-root > .MuiButton-label').click()
```

How can I change the location strategy, I've just started in cypress, it's my very first test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at [Paper-Button always as upper case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25160465/15239601)

> The material design spec for buttons specifies that the text should be uppercase

which means the text shown in the DOM is what you should search for

```
cy.contains('.MuiButton-label', 'text in same case as DOM has')  // fails if wrong case
```

or with a regex that has case-insensitive option

```
cy.contains('.MuiButton-label', /text in ANY case/i )            // succeeds for any case
```

Answer (score 1):

`.jss403` is generated by React each time you build. The other two classes are fixed and supplied by the Material-UI library.

Since you have a label, can you search on the text of the label?

```
cy.contains('.MuiButton-label', 'the-label-text')
```

If you can inspect the page with devtools, copy the section of HTML (use the right-click option 'Edit as HTML') and add it to your question, can then give a more precise answer.

---

Based on the MUI docs page [here](https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/), the element you would target for the first example button which has the text "Default" is

```
<span class="MuiButton-label">Default</span>
```

I cloned the page from the CodeSandbox link they give, and added a simple click handler to the Default button

**App - demo.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

...

export default function OutlinedButtons() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Button variant="outlined" onClick={() => { alert('clicked') }}>Default</Button>
```

**Test**

```js
it('clicks the MUI button', () => {

  cy.visit('http://localhost:3000')  // cloned the example and running it locally

  cy.contains('.MuiButton-label', 'Default')
    .click()                         // shows "(alert) clicked" 
                                     // in Cypress runner log

})
```

The alert does not actually show because Cypress suppresses it, but there is an entry in the log.

Comment: Timed out retrying after 30000ms: Expected to find content: 'AD' within the selector: '.MuiButton-label' but never did.

Comment: can I click click directly after contain text ? because it's not working already the contain !

Comment: No, clicking will not work if `.contains()` did not work. I'll add a test I've just tried.

Comment: thanks again for your try! I appreciate it, actually I posted how I solved the problem using another test

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved it !

using this code,

```
 cy.get('.MuiButtonBase-root > .MuiButton-label').eq(4).click({force: true})
```

I find out that I have 5 elements so using `eq(x)` to the initial code (by removing the variable part related to react.

Comment: I'd suggest that searching for label text is better than using position info, should be a lot less fragile.

Comment: You probably don't need `.MuiButtonBase-root` either, since `.MuiButton-label` is pretty specific.

Comment: Thanks for the idea: I tried this one 'cy.contains('.MuiButton-label', 'the-label-text')' but it was not working :(

Comment: So, just out of interest, what text is on the label? What does the `<span>` show?

Comment: <span class="MuiButton-label">the text I'm searching but it's in lower case </span>
do you think this is the reason why it's not working ? because the text is printed upper case in the UI level

Comment: That sounds possible. Not sure how it's upper-cased. There will be a way to check it in case-insensitive way, will post an answer.