# How to disable the text auto uppercase of a Button in Material UI v5?

Tags: material-ui

How can I turn off the auto uppercase function of `<Button>` in material UI 5?

```
<Button variant="contained">Hello</Button>
```

It will automatically turn the text to `HELLO`, but I just want to keep the original `Hello`. How can I do that?

Comment: This has been answered here [Paper-Button always as upper case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64201100/1998575)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply add this property to your button :

```
style={{textTransform: 'none'}}
```